# Why is my Netbeans 8 javascript auto-complete not working in my AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, netbeans

I saw a demo of Netbeans 8 showing javascript autocompletion for AngularJS objects.  In my test project, its not working.  It get autocompletion on directives when i type in "ng-"   but when i try to access the variables from a property object from a controller for example, the autocomplete isn't working.  My project can be downloaded from http://www.clearsoftinc.com/public_html/. As an example, if you load this project into netbeans and then go to index.html and go to line 28.  The "name" in the "product.name" expression should come up in autocomplete and it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you use the "controller as" feature, new in Angular 1.2. However this is not supported in NetBeans right now.

If you want to get the code completion, your `ng-controller` directives should look like

```
ng-controller="StoreController"
```

and all the properties that should be exposed to the page would have to be defined via `$scope`

```
app.controller("StoreController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = gems;
}]);
```

Note that this is (afaik) not an obsolete or even hacky way, it is 100% valid and correct code. With Angular 1.2, it is up to you if you want to use `$scope` or `this`

**Update:** Support for `controller as` is now part of NetBeans daily builds (download [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/)) and will be in upcoming NetBeans 8.1